# Selenium IDE - sel block plugin is not getting loaded in Firefox22

Tags: plugins, selenium-ide, firefox-22, selblocks-plugin

When opening Selenium IDE 2.2.0 in Firefox22, the following error message is displayed

"The following plugins were disabled due to errors while loading their code. See the Plugins section in the Selenium IDE Options dialog for individual plugin details.

sel-blocks@chris.noe"

On checking the Options >Plugin , it says that "ReferenceError: XML is not defined"

Sel Block version is 1.3

1. Can anyone let me know how should I fix the problem without
   downgrading the Firefox version?
2. Also is there any other selenium IDE plugin with
   for , foreach loop controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sel Blocks 1.3` is not compatible with Firefox 22. There were suggestions that you can manually remove one line from the plugin to get it to work.

The good news is that the plugin author has mentioned that a new version has been submitted to the Mozilla addons website and is waiting approval. You can [install the new latest version directly from here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/versions/).